# Override base url in swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Our service has two instances. Live is operational and has the URL .../bazaar and beta is for public testing and has the URL .../betabazaar.

We deployed a Swagger UI instanze and changed the url to fetch .../betabazaar/swagger.json which works. But when I use "try out" all requests goes to .../bazaar/...

I assume Swagger uses the @ServicePath parameter to fill the path. For both instances the @ServicePath is /bazaar. Our Nginx proxy server does the job for sending all requests for .../betabazaar/... to to beta instance.

So can I change the URL Swagger UI is using for "try it out" request in Swagger UI? Or do I need to change the @ServicePath in Java?

I already played with window.swaggerUi.setBasePath('/betabazaar'); but this leads to Swagger UI try to fetch http://example.com/api in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct call is

```
window.swaggerUi.setBasePath('/betabazaar');
```

and needs to be called in onComplete callback.

Comment: It is actually `window.swaggerUi.api.setBasePath('/betabazaar');`.

Answer (score 1):

You may override the basePath in the `onComplete` method by calling `setBasePath`:

```js
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
  ...
  onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi) {
    swaggerApi.setBasePath('/betabazaar')

    // Alternatively
    swaggerUi.api.setBasePath('/betabazaar')

    // Also this is possible
    window.swaggerUi.api.setBasePath('/betabazaar');
  }
}
```

It is also possible to override the host (which is what I was looking for by the way).

Comment: It's not working anymore with Swagger UI 4.11.0. At least, there is an error `Uncaught TypeError: swaggerApi is undefined` in the console. Modern Swagger seems to call the onComplete function with no args, and it hasn't got the setBasePath method.

Comment: @mymedia do you found a solution (for swagger UI 4.x)?